# How do you configure the number of replicas per table or database?

Tags: cockroachdb

On Cockroachdb, is it possible to configure the number of replicas per table or database?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use the `CONFIGURE ZONE` subcommand to do so. For a database, you can configure your replicas using `ALTER DATABASE <db> CONFIGURE ZONE USING num_replicas=<number>`. For table, it would be same as above except replace `DATABASE` keyword with the `TABLE` keyword. You can view your replication zone setup using the `SHOW ZONE CONFIGURATIONS` query. Please refer to the docs for more information: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/configure-zone.html